# CSS (no) hover issue (default cursor)

Tags: wordpress, css, css-selectors

I have an issue with CSS. In a Wordpress menu I want to add text, which is not a link. Therefore I added a link to # and now I would like to remove the coursor hand. Therefore I added no-hover to the CSS class of the menu, which is defined as:

```
.no-hover a:hover {
    cursor: default;
}
```

An extract from the menu looks like this:

```
<li id="menu-item-516" class="no-hover menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-516">
<a href="#">ABOUT</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-533" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-443 current_page_item menu-item-533 active ">
<a href="/history">History</a>
</li>
```

The whole CSS for the theme is here http://pastebin.com/mJ6tMUts - the bootstrap is here http://pastebin.com/bEQBUWUY

However, when I enable the CSS, the cursos on all items is the default one. How do I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: You should add more styles, because what you are posting here is fine and will do the trick. Something else prevents it from working.

Comment: I added the whole CSS now, which is here http://pastebin.com/mJ6tMUts - and the bootstrap.mini. is here http://pastebin.com/bEQBUWUY I understand that it "inherits it" but I don´t know where & how.

Comment: You didn't show HTML.

Comment: The original HTML output (without meta) is here: http://pastebin.com/9wZW0Qju - sorry I just copied the whole HTML just to be sure. It starts at pagination line 110

Comment: Unfortunately it's very hard to localize the problem when there are so many unnecesary HTML. If you can try to create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo, it would help a lot.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fefdh8rj/ - this show it probably the best

Comment: So what is the problem, I can see cursor is default.

Comment: The problem is, that the cursor shall not be default on history, only on about! That´s why About has the class="no-hover" and History not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments discussion, you probably want [direct child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors):

```
.no-hover > a:hover {
    cursor: default;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fefdh8rj/1/

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want any cursor then use like this

```
<a href="#" class="as">ABOUT</a>

.as{
    cursor:none !important;
}
```

[see more cursor here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `!important`

```
.no-hover a:hover {
    cursor: default !important;
}
```

JSFIDDLE DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8s78431c/